# How do you make a Text Label display how many rows there are in the table

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I am using Core Data and want a Text Label to display how many rows there are in the table, what code would I need to enter in the class file's to do this?

Comment: What is displayed in the table? I usually display an NSMutableArray, and can therefore use [NSMutableArray count] to fnd out how many rows are in the table.

Comment: It just displays what is the Default for Core Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your NSTableView's columns are bound to an NSArrayController, you can bind the value of the NSTextField label to your array controller's with controller key "arrangedObjects" and with a key path of `@count`. If you want to bind the text field to something like "x rows" where x is the number of rows, you would bind the "Display Pattern Value1" to the same (arrangedObjects.@count) and use "%{value1}@ rows" as the Display Pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a fetch request on your managed object context like you normally would, and call `countForFetchRequest:`. Don't forget to subscribe to `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` so you can update it when objects are added or removed!

Comment: Example Code, if thats possible please?

Comment: Joshua: If you don't know how to set up a fetch request or you don't know how to register as a local notification observer, read the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ and http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/